# Flume - Is it possible to read from HornetQ topics?

Tags: hadoop, jboss, jms, hornetq, flume

I would like to use flume in order to take data from a remote HornetQ topic and put the data inside HDFS.

I have a sample flume.conf file, which seems to allow to read from a remote ActiveMQ server:

```
# Name the components on this agent
a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.channels = c1

# Describe/configure the source
a1.sources.r1.type = jms
a1.sources.r1.initialContextFactory = org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
a1.sources.r1.connectionFactory = GenericConnectionFactory
a1.sources.r1.providerURL = tcp://10.xxx.xxx.xx:7676
a1.sources.r1.destinationName = topic_name
a1.sources.r1.destinationType = TOPIC

# Describe the sink
a1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:8020/data/flume/
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream


# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 1000
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 100

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

And especially, this part of the configuration file is problematic:

```
# Describe/configure the source
a1.sources.r1.type = jms
a1.sources.r1.initialContextFactory = org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
a1.sources.r1.connectionFactory = GenericConnectionFactory
a1.sources.r1.providerURL = tcp://10.xxx.xxx.xx:7676
a1.sources.r1.destinationName = topic_name
a1.sources.r1.destinationType = TOPIC
```

I only found on the internet some HornetQ sink plugins and some HornetQ channel plugin. But I did not found a source plugin.

So, is it possible to read data from HornetQ with Flume ? If yes, how ?

Thank you very much.